# Promise.then() but functions run async

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to Javascript and doing a crawler, I've created 4 Promise as these

```
var openConfig = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile('./config.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    config = JSON.parse(data);
    client = new MsTranslator({
      client_id: config.translatorId,
      client_secret: config.translatorSecret
    }, true)
    resolve();
  })
})

var openFile = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Opening file...')
  fs.readFile('./writing/writing.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    writing = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('Done parsing file');
    resolve();
  })
})

var ask = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  })
  rl.question('Which lesson do you want to add? ', (ans) => {
    lessonId = ans;
    rl.close();
    resolve();
  })
})

var createLesson = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Now processing lesson ' + lessonId);
})
```

then call the first Promise

```
openConfig
  .then(() => {
    return openFile;
  })
  .then(() => {
    return ask;
  })
  .then(() => {
    return createLesson;
  })
```

but as I run, the console show

```
Opening file...
Which lesson do you want to add? Now processing lesson undefined
Done parsing file
```

which I understood as my promises are wrong and my function run async. Can you help me to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You are creating promises up-front, you should create functions that return promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning new Promises to vars (these run as soon as created), you should wrap them into functions, which in turn return a new Promise

To help you understand here's a simplified example:

```
function p1 (data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(Object.assign(data, {a:1}));
    });
}

function p2 (data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(Object.assign(data, {b:2}));
    });
}

function p3 (data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(Object.assign(data, {c:3}));
    });
}

p1({z:0})
.then(p2)
.then(p3)
.then((data)=>console.log(data))
```

This results in `{ z: 0, a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`

See here if you wish to experiment a bit with the above: https://repl.it/DwNB/0

---

On a separate note, if you are using promises, you should also handle errors in the chain in a final `.catch()` instead of synchronously `throw`ing midway. That's what the `reject` callback is for!

Answer (score 2):

Promises are not "called". In your `then` chain, you only sequentially await them - but the tasks were already started when you *created* the promises. If you want to sequence the actions, put them in functions.

Btw, your code contains multiple typical mistakes. [Don't use global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572), and always [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) at the lowest possible level:

```
function openFile(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./config.json', (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err); // never `throw err` in non-promise callbacks!
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
function openJSON(path) {
  return openFile(path).then(JSON.parse);
}
function openConfig(path) {
  return openJSON(path).then(config =>
    new MsTranslator({
      client_id: config.translatorId,
      client_secret: config.translatorSecret
    }, true)
  )
}
function ask(question) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    })
    rl.question(question, ans => {
      rl.close();
      resolve(ans); // always resolve to *something*
    });
  });
}

readConfig('./config.json')
.then(client => {
  console.log('Opening file...')
  return openJSON('./writing/writing.json');
})
.then(writing => {
  console.log('Done parsing file');
  return ask('Which lesson do you want to add? ');
})
.then(lessonId => {
  console.log('Now processing lesson ' + lessonId);
});
```